# Merging two columns into one column but the data will not concat, another cell

Tags: mysql

Im trying to merging two columns into one column but not concatenating them,
Im a new student i know it's not a detailed problem expression because im having a hard time to express the problem and english is not my first language

**User table**

```
id | firstname | lastname
1  |  john | doe


**Techinican table**

id | firstname | lastname
1 | mary   | doe
```

I'm concatenating them like this

```
concat (users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) as seller1,
concat (technicians.first_name, ' ', technicians.last_name) as seller2,
concat(seller1,seller2 )as seller
```

i trying to have a result like this

```
**Seller**

John Doe
Mary Doe
```

One column but different cell

Comment: In order to clarify your question, please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For vertically joining you use [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)

```
SELECT concat (users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) as seller1 FROM user
UNION
SELECT concat (technicians.first_name, ' ', technicians.last_name) as seller2 FROM Technician
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this;

```
select concat (users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) as seller from user_table) union (select concat (technicians.first_name, ' ', technicians.last_name) as seller from techincan_table;
```